# How do I handle regex filters on binary row keys and column qualifiers in Bigtable?

Tags: go, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

In my current Bigtable design, all my row keys, column qualifiers and values are binary values. I'm using the Go client, and simply casting `[]byte` keys to `string` allows me to do write data (seemingly) without issue.

However, this poses some issues when using Bigtable APIs that involve regexes on keys/values, such as the [filters](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#Filter) `bigtable.ColumnFilter`, `bigtable.ValueFilter` and `bigtable.RowKeyFilter` in the Go client [library](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable).

I'm looking for recommendations or best practices for these questions:

- How can I escape the binary values to safely use these filters without Bigtable accidentally interpreting a byte as a regex character? E.g. to plainly match a column qualifier byte-by-byte using `bigtable.ColumnFilter`.
- In extension, what hoops do I need to jump through to use regexes safely over these binary values? E.g., I want to use `bigtable.RowKeyFilter` to match row keys that start and end with specific bytes (I'm aware that will have bad performance).

For context, this is a simplified version of my schema:

- Row keys: `[16 byte UUID][8 byte big-endian uint][8 byte big-endian uint]`
- Column qualifiers: `[8 byte big-endian uint][8 byte big-endian uint]`
- Values: `[8 byte big-endian uint]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[to escape all regex characters use](https://godoc.org/regexp#QuoteMeta) : `regexp.QuoteMeta`

package **regexp** also can help you to use regexes safely over binary values without any issue. however, keep in mind that

> All characters are UTF-8-encoded code points.